# sudo does not work after purging an app

Tags: python, sudo, uninstall, directory, purge

After I removed an app with purge, I cannot use `sudo` or `apt-get` any more and get this error.

```
-bash: /usr/bin/sudo: No such file or directory
```

Do you have any suggestions?

version: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: What app did you remove?

Answer (score 2):

Be careful when you remove system's software. I can think 2 solutions:

1. Use the command `pkexec apt install sudo` in order to install sudo.
2. Reboot and choose "Advanced Options" in the grub menu in order to boot in a root shell and run `apt install sudo` command in order to install sudo.

After you install sudo look at the apt logs in order to see what other packages which depended on sudo package got removed and install them again.

Comment: I was just now typing these exact commands ;).

Comment: Thank you for response, I saw your response quite late so reinstalled ubuntu.